# Will I be punished for serial up voting

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I mostly visit C#, SQL And SQL Server tags, sometimes I found some users are good in that tags, and I visits profiles and read questions and answers of them for knowledge  As well as give Upvote to him if question or answer is good.

But As per serial voting Will be I ban or suspended.

I am asking because, it's not for revenge purpose or friends helping, If I got quality then I will upvote it.

Comment: Sounds good.  Why do you think there would be a problem?

Comment: What you're doing is absolutely fine. That doesn't mean that the automated scripts won't sometimes pick up your upvotes as serial voting if you upvote content of the same user to frequently. But they will just be automatically reversed, you won't be banned. Knowing it, maybe be a little more conservative with your upvotes when you're browsing by user.

Comment: Well, if that behaviour would be considered _fine_, then it is just another example for the double standard on Stack Overflow. Same mods already said that you shouldn't go to a user profile to check their other contributions if you found a really bad post (i.e. provide more downvotes than upvotes (if any) for these posts). Thus they concluded to avoid checking a user profile and just vote on the questions when they occur naturally (throw the main page or review queues for example).

Comment: @Tom I never check user profiles for down or upvotes, Here my aim to asking that sometimes I observed that XYZ user's Questions or answers are good so I visit his profile and read his answers or questions to increase my knowledge you can considor it like reading a book. and that time If I feels Its a good quality then I vote up

Comment: Imran, don't get me wrong, I don't have an issue with that as long as you vote based on the content, not the user. But some mods already said that we shouldn't do that for downvotes (not revenge downvotes, I'm still talking about downvoting bad content), thus doing so for upvotes should have the same restrictions. I would prefer that these restrictions wouldn't exist, but as already said by other users, these votes can get reverted by the vote reversal script.

Comment: @Tom, So we have to avoid upvoting also, cause my upvotes will reverse by reversal script

Comment: Yes, with the current system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just vote for content, not for users, then you won't ever get banned for it. Your votes may get reversed by the serial voting reversal script though, if you happen to land a bunch on a specific user in a short timespan. You should avoid that.

Generally you should be voting as you naturally come across posts, not going through a specific user's answers and then voting on them.

Comment: OP specifically says they visit user profiles and find posts to upvote that way, which is against the rules, even if they only vote things up which they find truly useful. You might want to phrase this answer more strongly.

Comment: @Dukeling Even doing that, if he only ends up upvoting a couple and doesn't keep doing it for the very same user, it'll rarely be reverted. The script is _very_ conservative and hardly anyone is gonna get a CM involved in reverting that by hand